# Displaying different developer names from one Apple Enterprise Account

Tags: ios, enterprise

Can I publish apps from one account (enterprise) with different seller's display names in app store?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you mean a corporate membership or an enterprise membership?  Assuming you mean corporate membership, the answer is no; Apps will be published under the legal name of the corporation that has the membership

Comment: Thank you, I really mean a corporate membership :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are not allowed to use the enterprise account to publish apps in the app store.

The Enterprise account is intended to be used in-house only, see here: [Compare Memberships](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).